# Create an iframe and the contents of the iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, printing

I'd like to create an iframe (using jquery) and append it to my page, but instead of specifying a src attribute, I'd like to just build the page myself in JavaScript/jQuery. The reason I'm doing this is because I'd like to create a print prompt for a single image on the page without opening a new window.

Basically, I'm trying to implement this print feature:
http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/printpart.html
But without having to actually open a new window. I want to do this on a single page with a hidden iframe.

I want to do something like this:

```
 function loadOtherPage() {
    $("<iframe><html><body><img src='image.png'/><script>window.print</script></body></html></iframe>")
      .hide()
      .appendTo("body");      
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the iframe gets created but with an empty head and body. I cannot edit it after its creation because of browser security features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the iframe like so:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>')
```

Then append the iframe

```
$('body').append(iframe);
```

You can then write to it's contents like so:

```
var iframe_styles = iframe[0].contentWindow.document.write('<style>body{ background-color: #fafafa; }</style>');
```

Add some body content:

```
 var iframe_content = iframe[0].contentWindow.document.write('<body>test</body>');
```

Comment: I get an error on iframe[0].contentWindow, which is null according to Chrome.

Comment: sorry, you had to append it first. I updated my answer

Comment: Beautiful! Finally got this working. Thanks a bunch!